# How to test if a Publisher is a cached one in reactor spring?

Tags: spring, kotlin, project-reactor

I have two publishers:

```
val text = Mono.just("demo")

val cachedText = Mono.just("demo").cache()
```

How can I test check if one is cached and the other isn't?

I know that the cached one is of type "reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime" but this type is internal. I see no chance to test against that?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why does it matter that it is cached? `Mono` doesn't expose that sort of information

Comment: Usually I would agree that the publisher wouldn't care about implementation details. But in this case we will reuse the publisher of a "heavy-operation-result" to improve performance. We want to make sure that this improvement (".cache") is in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're sure this is an "either the `Mono` is cached with a specific configuration or it isn't cached" situation, you could try to see what the `Scannable.from(mono).stepName()` returns, but that is only marginally better than relying on the class name.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Simon.
```Mono.just("").cache().let { Scannable.from(it).stepName() }.let { assertThat(it).isEqualTo("cacheTime") }```

...did the trick for me!